# Android backpressed not working

Tags: java, android, back-button, onbackpressed

I'm trying to build a simple **login** & **registration** application in android. My problem is that I want to handle `backpressed()` but it is not working.

> Example: I'm having 3 activities: **signin**, **register** and **verify**. What I need is if we back click on register or verify, the navigation should go to **signin** and if we back click on **signin**, the application should close.

I have tried these lines of code but they are not working. They will navigate to previously visited activity.
This code is of **signin** activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    finish();
}
```

This code is of register activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: are you using toolbar? or action bar back press?

Comment: you should call super in onBackPressed method!

Comment: I'm using device back button @rafsanahmad007

Comment: not working @Ahmad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I need is that if we back click on register or verify, the
>   navigation should go to signin and if we back click on signin, the
>   application should close.

To go to `SignInActivity` `onBackpressd()` from `Verify` and `RegisterActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
    finishAffinity();
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In `SignInActivity`:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();            
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is somehow working but not as i want. For eg. if i'm on register and i backpressed it is going to signin but if i again go to register then verify and backpressed it is going to register.

Comment: Yes @tahsinRupam

Comment: 21 @tahsinRupam

Comment: yup working ! Thanks. But still having one issue. the app is not closing normally like other apps, it looks like it is crashing

Comment: Still crashing @tahsinRupam

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're building for API>16

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  finishAffinity();
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for sure!!

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finishAffinity();
        System.exit(0);


    }
```

Comment: what about this?

Answer (score 0):

Finish will always go to the previous activity on the stack.  The intent flags need to be set when your activity is LAUNCHED, not when your activity is being killed.